# Prove the Axiom of Replacement implies the Axiom of Specification.

Tags: set-theory

The Axiom of Specification says that:

For a set $ A$ and objects $x\in A$,for any object $y$ there exists a set:
$$ y \in \{x: P(x) \wedge x \in A\} \implies y \in A \text{ and } P(y)$$

Where $P(x)$ is a statement pertaining to $x$.

The Axiom of Replacement says that:

For a set $ A$ and objects $x\in A$,for any object y, suppose we have a statement $P(x,y)$, pertaining to $x$ and $y$ such that for each $x$ there is at most one $y$ for which $P(x,y)$ is  true, then there exists a set, such that for any object  z,
$$ z\in \{y:P(x,y) \text{ s.t } x \in A \} \implies P(x,z) \text{ for } x \in A$$

I can see that the AOR is stronger than the AOS. If we let $P(x,y)$ be whether $y$ is in the same set as $x$ then $P(x,y)$ is a true of false statement and hence it will follow that if $P(x,y)$ is true then $ y \in A \text{ and } P(y)$. Does this hold any water?

I have sketched diagrams, to try and motivate a solution but have failed.

I am editing this question simply because I don't understand the answers to the other posts. ( I have tried...) So I am going to add an answer to mine.

MY ATTEMPT:

Let A be a set, then for any object $y$ let $\gamma$ be defined as follows:

$$\gamma(x) = x \text{ if } \theta(x) \text{ for } x \in A$$
$$\gamma(x) = y \text{ if } !\theta(x) \text{ for } x \in A$$

Then by the Axiom of replacement There exists a set $B$ such that

$$B = \{\gamma(x): x \in A, \gamma(x) = x\} = \{x:\theta(x), x \in A\}$$

The last set in the above statement implies the Axiom of separation.

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/how-do-the-separation-axioms-follow-from-the-replacement-axioms).

Comment: And this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680376/proving-separation-from-replacement).

Comment: Your formulation of the Axiom schema of Spec is a little bit "strange"; it would be batter to say : for any set $A$ and formula $P(x)$ there exists a set: $\{ x : P(x) \land x \in A \}$.

Comment: Thanks, i see how it strange now. I will fix ASAP.

Comment: I am still finding it difficult, even though i understand this is a duplicate I cant seem to grasp the solution given by Asaf

Comment: If you don't understand the answer's that are given for the other question, rather than posting the question again, it would be a better idea to post a question like, "*I was reading this answer [post link to answer here], and couldn't quite understand it. Could someone explain this answer to someone of my background? [insert details of your background/experience here]*".

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/how-do-the-separation-axioms-follow-from-the-replacement-axioms The accepted answer to this question is what i am having trouble understanding. I have just completed my first year in university (UK).  I have little\no experience with Axiomatic set theory.

Comment: In a nutshell, take the *Replacement axiom (schema)* and use as formula $\varphi (u,v)$ the formula $u=v  \land \varphi(u)$. This one satisfy the condition of "functionality" needed by *Replacement* and after some "manipulations" you will get the result : $∃b∀x \ [x∈b \leftrightarrow \varphi(x) ∧ x∈a]$. See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/680376/proving-separation-from-replacement) for details.