# How to deduce Axiom Schema of Replacement from Axiom of Separation?

Tags: set-theory

I have two questions regarding this issue.

1. In addition to Axiom Schema of Replacement, Which axioms do we need to deduce Axiom of Separation?
2. How to deduce Axiom of Separation from Axiom Schema of Replacement?

Axiom of Separation: $\forall w \forall x \exists y \forall z [z \in y \iff  (z \in x \land \varphi(z, w, x ) )]$

Axiom Schema of Replacement:$\forall w \forall A [ (\forall x \in A \implies \exists ! y \varphi(x,y,w, A)) \implies (\exists B \forall x (x \in A \implies  \exists y \in B \varphi(x,y,w, A)))]$

Many thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the title ;)

Comment: How are they axioms if they are deducible? @MaximeRamzi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** : consider $\psi(x,y, w, A) : x=y\land x\in A \land \phi(x, w, A)$

Comment: Hi @Max, I can interpret the role of $x$ as  $\psi(x,y, w, A)$ holds true for $x, y, w$. Can you interpret the role of A in $\psi(x,y, w, A)$? Is it redundant to include both $x$ and $A$ in $\psi(x,y, w, A)$, since $x$ is clearly in $A$.

Comment: Yeah of course I introduced some redundancies

Comment: But from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932781/definability-and-the-separation-and-replacement-axiom-schemata, and from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory#6._Axiom_schema_of_replacement, they both include $\color{blue}{A}$ into $\varphi(x,y,\vec{w}, \color{blue}{A})$! Please clarify my doubt!

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant when I wrote $x\in A$. For the $A$ in the formula, it's surely not dedundant, but finding examples where it isn't may be tough. By the way I just took a look at your axiom of replacement and there's something wrong with it : it shouldn't be "$\forall x\in A, \exists ! y$ blabla" but "for all $x\in A$, there's *at most* one $y$  blabla"

Comment: So any statement of Axiom Schema of Replacement that uses $\exists ! y$ is wrong? As a result, the statements of Axiom Schema of Replacement in two links, which I have given above, are wrong two? Is there any symbols that stand for "there's at most one y"?

Comment: Well it's not *wrong*, it's another version; less useful in practice. Now that I think about it, with a slight adjustment you can still deduce the axiom schema of separation from it, but not as easily as what I did (there must be a case distinction).  There's no designated "consensual" symbol. Sometimes people use $\exists^{\leq 1} y$ (which is an abbreviation, like $\exists !$)