# Reference request: Reflection as a single axiom interpreting the whole of ZFC?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, first-order-logic

Working in first order languge $\mathcal L(\in, W)$, where $W$ is a constant symbol.

**Reflection:** if $\varphi$ is a formula in $\mathcal L(\in)$, in which $x$ is free, and $\vec{p}$ is the string of all of its parameters, and if $\psi$ is a formula in which $z$ is free and $y$ not free, then all closures of: $$\vec{p} \in W \wedge \exists x (\varphi) \to  \forall c\exists x [\varphi\wedge \exists y \in W \ \forall z (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in x \wedge \psi)  ] $$; are axioms.

Now with Extensionality this would interpret all axioms of $\text{ZFC}$ since it would trivially interpret Harvey [Friedman](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/u.osu.edu/dist/1/1952/files/2014/01/TalkAxiomSetThy-ts05xn.pdf) $\text{K(W)}$ theory (page 3). Although I'm not sure but I think even Extensionality is interpretable using the above scheme only.

Has there been prior attempts to non-trivially shortly axiomatize ZFC with a single comprehension schema? and had this schema been studied before specially in absence of Extensionality?

Comment: Well, [the Replacement scheme implies the Separation scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32483/how-do-the-separation-axioms-follow-from-the-replacement-axioms), so the answer to your first question is immediately "yes."

Comment: To me all of the axioms of set union, power and infinity, all are individual comprehension axioms. What is not a comprehension axiom is Extensionality, Foundation and Choice. And by the way Replacement doesn't interpret all the others

Comment: Very interesting question. Did you ever find an answer? I have a related question [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/404966/harvey-friedmans-minimalist-axioms-for-set-theory).