# definition of image in axiomatic set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

From axiom of replacement:
I have given a set $S$ and have relation $R(x,y)$ such that $x \in S$, then there exist unique $y \in T$ which is image of set $S$ where $T$ is also a set.

But I can use Axiom schema of comprehension where I have $P(y)$ as predicate, then there exist a subset $T \subset S$ such that it consist of exactly those $y \in S $ for which $P(y)$ is true. In symbols I have:
$$T = \{y\in S|P(y)\}$$
Then it says that axiom schema of comprehension is a consequence of axiom of replacement as:

$\bullet\,$ $\,\lnot(\exists y\in S : P(y))$ then define $T = \phi$

$\bullet\,$ $\, \exists \,\hat{y}\in S : P(y)$ then by definition I have
$$\text{when } P(x) \text{ is true, then } R(x)=y$$
$$\text{when } P(x) \text{ is false, then } R(\hat{y})=y$$
From all of this $T$ is image is image of set $S$ under relation $R(x,y)$

My confusion is:

$ \color{red}{\text{ how }y\in S \text{ and axiom schema of comprehension is a consequence of axiom of replacement}}$
Please provide me one example also. Thanks in advance!

note: I searched on internet and it didn't help and I am physics person and started learning set theory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Long comment*

See [Relation to the axiom schema of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification#Relation_to_the_axiom_schema_of_replacement) for the derivation of Separation from Replacement.

Please, note that in the [Axiom Schema of Replacement](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/ZF.html) we use a formula $\varphi$ that is functional (which relates each set $x$ to a unique set $y$) and not a relation $R$ (i.e. a set).

For a relation $R$, i.e. a subset of $S \times T$, we have the domain $S$ and the codomain $T$. We define the [range (or: image)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/sets/domain-range-codomain.html) of $R$ as the subset of the codomain:

> $\text{Ran}(R) = \{ y \in T \mid R(x,y) \text { for some } x \in S \}$.

Thus, by definition: $\text{Ran}(R) \subseteq T$.

Comment: $R(x, y)$ be $x = y\wedge P(x)$. $T =\{(x,x) :\phi(x)\} =\{(x,y) :R(x,y)\}$. $R(x,y)$ is a functional formula. Therefore, we have that The Separation Axioms follow from the Replacement Schema.
 $T$ $=$ $\{y : (\exists x\in X)R(x, y)\}$ $=$ $\{y:(\exists x\in S)x = y\wedge P(x)\}$ $=$ $\{x:(\exists x\in S)\phi(x)\}$ $=$ $\{x\in S :P (x)\}$.

Comment: i am not getting how T is image

Comment: This is a functional formula (i.e. for every u there is at most a single v for which φ(u,v,p) holds) and it is easy to verify that the image of φ(u,v,a) is indeed $$\{x\in a\mid \phi(x)\}$$    This is from : https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32493/956732